# cant read files either way using bufferdreader or datainputstream(getting EOFexception)?

Tags: java

Im a beginner in java.when using bufferedReader
program freezes when reaching readLine method.
when using DatainputStream, readUTF method throws EOF exception instantly without reading any lines(the file do have content).
this is my code:

```
public DataInputStream read(){
 try {
DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(getChosenFile())));
return din;
}
 catch(IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     System.exit(0);
 }
 return null;
}
 public void regexCheck(String regex,String FileStr,int line) {
   Pattern check=Pattern.compile(regex);
 Matcher   regMatcher=check.matcher(FileStr);
 while(regMatcher.find())
 {
     if(regMatcher.group().length()!=0) {
        ar.append(regMatcher.group()+"  "+line+"\n");
     }

  }
  }
  public void reader(String regex) {
 int line=0;
boolean eof=false;
 String c;
 try {
 while(!eof)
 {
     line++;
     c=read().readUTF();

    regexCheck(regex,c,line);
 }
read().close();
 }
 catch(EOFException e) {
    eof=true;
 }
 catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     System.exit(0);
 }
 catch(IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     System.exit(0);
 }


 }
 }
```

Comment: Every time you call `read()`, you are creating a brand new FileInputStream.  Call it exactly once, outside your loop.  This might or might not be the cause of your problem.

Comment: @VGR I changed that . still the same error . thanks BTW